# How to validate entity existence by ID?

Tags: typescript, database, validation, web, nestjs

Typically, incoming data validation in Nest.js is achieved through [`ValidationPipe()`](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#auto-validation):

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true }));
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT);
}
```

But validating entity existence by ID requires additional validation logic.

How to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nestjs Guards, as you have the access to the request context so using the id coming from the request you can check if the entity exists in the database and by returning false you are by default throwing 403 error you just enforce throwing 404 error

Comment: Can you give an example of such a validation?